# My kivy code is not displaying anything. Please tell me where I am going wrong

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

i have designed a kivy form which takes some information from the user..But none of it is getting displayed..Please tell me where I am going wrong.

My code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout    

class Widgets(Widget):
    pass


class YourDiaryApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Widgets()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    YourDiaryApp().run()
```

Kivy code:

```
<Widgets>:
    FloatLayout:

        Label:
            text:'What do you want me to call you'
        TextInput:
            id:username

        Label:
            text:'What do you wanna call me'
        TextInput:
            id:diaryname

        Label:
            text:'What will be your password'
        TextInput:
            id:password

        Button:
            text:'Complete Setup'
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your KV file named "yourDiaryApp.kv"? From the [docs](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#how-to-load-kv:):

> There are two ways to load Kv code into your application:
>
> By name convention:
>
> Kivy looks for a Kv file with the same name as your App class in lowercase, minus “App” if it ends with ‘App’ e.g:
>
> ```
> MyApp -> my.kv
> ```

My guess would be the KV code isn't being loaded.

Comment: Yes bro!! My naming convention was wrong..i named the kv file yourdiaryapp.kv..Thanks for your help...